# PHP exec() and spaces in paths

Tags: php, path, exec

I'm executing the following in a PHP application:

```
  $source = '/home/user/file.ext';
  $output_dir = $this->setOutputString();

  chdir('/home/ben/xc/phplib/bgwatcher-2011a/a01/');
  exec('php bin/createjob.php $source $output_dir', $output);

  return $output[0];
```

The problem is this: I have control over `$source`, but not `$output_dir`, which is a legacy Windows filesystem, and there are spaces in the path.  An example `$output_dir` is:

```
/home/vol1/district id/store id/this_is_the_file.html
```

When inserting the output string into the `exec()` function, I have tried both:

`addslashes($output_dir)` and `'"' . $output_dir . '"'` to escape the entire output string.  In the first case, the path gets concatenated to:

`/home/vol1/districtthis_is_the_file.html`

... where everything between the first space and the filename gets dropped.  In the second case, `exec()` appears to throw a shoe and doesn't execute properly - unfortunately, the error message is getting lost in the machinery - I can provide it if it's absolutely necessary, but I'm also under time constraints to find a solution.

What's the solution, here?  Do I `sprintf()` the entire string for `exec()`?  I'm very confused as to why `addslashes` isn't working correctly to escape the spaces, and I assume it has something to do with sanitization with exec(), but I can't find any documentation to back it up.

**Update:** I've tried escapeshellarg() and preg_replace() without success.  Thinking about this further, do I need to double-escape the path?  Or escape the path and the command?  If the path is being unescaped once by exec(), and once by PHP before it executes the command, does it stand to reason that I need to account for both escapes?  Or is that not how it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php),

> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted in database queries etc. **These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte)**.

Looks like you'll have to preg_replace the spaces yourself.

**Edit:**

Even though this is the topic of another discussion, if performance is an issue, then after looking into it a little more, it seems that `str_replace` *is* actually quite a bit faster than `preg_replace`:

> The test labeled "str_replace()" was
>   the faster by 0.9053 seconds (it took
>   10.3% the time.)
>
> The first test took 1.0093 seconds. (`preg_replace`)
>
> The second test took 0.104 seconds. (`str_replace`)

[Benchmark found here.](http://net-beta.net/ubench/index.php?t=preg1)

Comment: Just to check my lack of RegExp-fu, is this correct?

    `preg_replace("/\s/", "\\ ", $this->output_dir)`;

Comment: For added speed, or just to be different, maybe use `str_replace()`?

Comment: When I tried this, the string still truncated at the first space and the createjob.php failed.  Hell's bells - I think I need to double-escape this!  Or escape the entire command ...

Answer (score 12):

I don't believe `addslashes()` does anything with spaces.  `escapeshellarg()` might be what you want instead. [Docs on escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Comment: I tried using escapeshellarg() on the $output_dir string, and the string still truncated on the first space it encountered.

Answer (score 10):

From the PHP doc ([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)),

> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted in database queries etc. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).

This won't do anything to the spaces. What you will need to do is use `str_replace()` to add slashes, like this:

`$new_string = str_replace(" ", "\\ ", $old_string);`

Answer (score 5):

I've used `exec()` with paths with spaces before, on both Windows and Linux hosts, and in both cases quoting the path worked perfectly for me.

That said, if you have no control over the safety of a shell argument, *always* run it through `escapeshellarg()` first!

Answer (score 3):

You can very well use *shell* quotes, since that is what all exec commands run through:

```
exec("php bin/createjob.php '$source' '$output_dir'", $output);
```

It btw works not just for arguments, but also for the command itself:

```
exec('"/bin/echo" "one parameter"');
```

Use `escapeshellcmd()` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me when using exec() with soffice(LibreOffice):

```
$file_name = "Some, file name.xlsx";
exec('/usr/bin/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf '."'".$file_name."'".' 2>&1', $output, $r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes and escape character together to work out this.

```
$fileName = "filename with spaces.pdf";
exec("php bin/createjob.php >\"".$fileName."\" 2> error.log" , $output, $return);
```