# php exec() with arguments containing spaces

Tags: php, shell

I want to use PHP to run a shell command that takes a directory as an argument. The problem is, this directory name contains both single quotes and spaces. In shell, if the directory is called "I'm a directory", this would be something like:
`ls I\'m\ a \ directory`

However, I am not able to get this working when invoking through PHP. I tried 
`exec('ls I\'m\ a\ directory')`
 and many other variations, but none of them seem to work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP exec() and spaces in paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489613/php-exec-and-spaces-in-paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
passthru('ls "I\'m a directory"');
```

exec() returns the last line of output, which might not be what you expected.  Compare it to this:

```
exec('ls "I\'m a directory"', $outvar);
print_r($outvar);
```

I assume all have read the fine manual, but here it is, just in case:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Example proof-of-concept session on FreeBSD:

```
501:~$ mkdir "I'm a directory"
502:~$ ls -lrt
drwxr-xr-x   2 cxj  cxj       512 Jul  2 19:32 I'm a directory
drwxr-xr-x  33 cxj  cxj      2048 Jul  2 19:32 .
503:~$ cd I\'m\ a\ directory/
504:~/I'm a directory$ touch foo bar baz
505:~/I'm a directory$ cd ..
506:~$ cat - > test.php
<?php passthru('ls "I\'m a directory"'); ?>
507:~$ cat test.php
<?php passthru('ls "I\'m a directory"'); ?>
508:~$ php test.php
bar
baz
foo
```

Comment: I will try, but I doubt this is the problem. It's true that echo exec() only gets the last line of output, but it should not be blank.
For example, exec('ls ~') gives me the name of one file.

Comment: Nope, I still don't get any output.

Comment: What's your system?  It works fine for me on Mac OSX and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3):

There is php function [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) for this. You enter whatever string you need and result is string formated so you can use it as one argument in shell:

```
$rawArgument = "I'm a directory";
$escapedArgumment = escapeshellarg($rawArgument);
exec("ls $escapedArgumment");
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to double escape your slashes correctly to ensure they don't get eaten by the string.

Part of your problem is that `\'` is being eaten and passed to the command line as just `'`.

Compare these:

```
echo 'ls I\'m\ a\ directory';
echo "\n";
echo "ls I\'m\ a\ directory"; //Note double quotes
echo "\n";
echo 'ls I\\\'m\\ a\\ directory';
echo "\n";
echo "ls I\\\'m\\ a\\ directory";  //Note double quotes
```

Results in:

```
ls I'm\ a\ directory
ls I\'m\ a\ directory
ls I\'m\ a\ directory
ls I\\'m\ a\ directory
```

So what you really want is either of these:

```
exec('ls I\\\'m\ a\ directory')
exec("ls I\'m\ a\ directory")
```

Comment: As in, it doesn't output anything. I've tried both your suggestions before posting. The code works fine for directories that have normal names.